How to classify/demultiplex fastq files using header
I sequenced some samples with Nanopore Barcoding Kit, and used dorado to basecall and demultiplex based on the barcodes.
Since Dorado main ouput is useless bam files, I used the --emit-fastq parameter to get a fastq file for data manipulation and analysis. It happens that dorado only outputted a single fastq file and didn't demultiplex as expected.
I checked the fastq file, and what dorado did was adding the barcode information in the fasta header.
7b751f1902912_dna_r10.4.1_e8.2_400bps_sup@v4.3.0_SQK-RBK114-24_barcode01
75e37ed8-7d99-4442-bd8d-64a06f70da84    st:Z:2024-08-11T05:19:10.972+00:00  RG:Z:16b7818be41d06b1e531609ca967b751f1902912_dna_r10.4.1_e8.2_400bps_sup@v4.3.0_SQK-RBK114-24_barcode01
45724d14-85f2-41b6-aea4-2d6a62355aa6    st:Z:2024-08-11T05:19:22.944+00:00  RG:Z:16b7818be41d06b1e531609ca967b751f1902912_dna_r10.4.1_e8.2_400bps_sup@v4.3.0_SQK-RBK114-24_barcode21
d2721e13-f430-4005-925b-4d068dad5197    st:Z:2024-08-11T05:19:16.405+00:00  RG:Z:16b7818be41d06b1e531609ca967b751f1902912_dna_r10.4.1_e8.2_400bps_sup@v4.3.0_SQK-RBK114-24_barcode07
2f9236ed-8cae-4704-9c16-892c0b00e3fc    st:Z:2024-08-11T05:19:10.533+00:00  RG:Z:16b7818be41d06b1e531609ca967b751f1902912_dna_r10.4.1_e8.2_400bps_sup@v4.3.0
aeaed141-84c9-4636-bbdb-7256684bda35    st:Z:2024-08-11T05:19:03.441+00:00  RG:Z:16b7818be41d06b1e531609ca967b751f1902912_dna_r10.4.1_e8.2_400bps_sup@v4.3.0_SQK-RBK114-24_barcode01
1c3546fa-99cf-4eb9-b9d9-83486707ea58    st:Z:2024-08-11T05:18:17.934+00:00  RG:Z:16b7818be41d06b1e531609ca967b751f1902912_dna_r10.4.1_e8.2_400bps_sup@v4.3.0_SQK-RBK114-24_barcode07
a3e1e263-b48c-4738-8eb3-e3d1505f1c51    st:Z:2024-08-11T05:19:11.925+00:00  RG:Z:16b7818be41d06b1e531609ca967b751f1902912_dna_r10.4.1_e8.2_400bps_sup@v4.3.0_SQK-RBK114-24_barcode06
cd6220ba-5635-4a8f-b133-cd5264066dc8    st:Z:2024-08-11T05:19:03.645+00:00  RG:Z:16b7818be41d06b1e531609ca967b751f1902912_dna_r10.4.1_e8.2_400bps_sup@v4.3.0_SQK-RBK114-24_barcode01

Thus, the barcode information is in the sequence header.
How can I split/bin the sequences based on the sequence header?

I tried using porechop, but porechop put many sequences in the missclassified/none fastq file.

This question is not about programming. It will be better suited for other sites, specially the ones devoted to bioinformatics.

Why do you consider the bam file useless?
BTW, it is not clear what are you showing us, but for sure that is not a fasta file.
